# Adding callback to jquery .submit() to read error responses from uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've got an iframe #uploadTarget which I'm using for image uploads:

```
function uploadImage(){

    if ($('#imageUploader').val().length > 0){
        $('#uploadingIndicator').show();

        // set form params such that it uploads image
        $('#uploadForm').attr("action", uploadUrl);
        $('#uploadForm').attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        $('#uploadForm').attr("target", 'uploadTarget');

        // submit for image upload
        $('#uploadForm').submit();
        resetFormAttributes();

        //console.log($('#uploadTarget').contents().find('body').text());

    } else {
        resetFormAttributes();
        $('#uploadForm').submit();
    }
}
```

When image upload is done, the page inside the iframe executes javascript which calls doneUploading outside the iframe.

In the event where the file is too big or an error occurred and an error page is displayed in the iframe, the doneUpload function is not called.

Is it possible to have some sort of a callback function that triggers after $('#uploadForm').submit() completed (in which case I'll read the page for error responses)?

If not, how would I read error responses being returned inside the iframe?

Comment: Are you using AJAX to do the submission? If so, you can use the AJAX callback function. Otherwise, I don't think there's a way.

Comment: @Barmar AJAX can't be used for image uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you trigger the `doneUploading()` function when the upload succeeds, then you should trigger a `failedUploading()` function when the upload fails. The content of the iframe can be accessed through jQuery's [`contents()` function](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

```
function failedUploading() {
    var data = $('#uploadTarget').contents();
}
```

#### Edit

Or, you could attach a one-time `load` event listener to the iframe directly after submitting the form:

```
resetFormAttributes();
$('#uploadForm').submit();
$('#uploadTarget').one('load', function() {
    var data = $('#uploadTarget').contents();
});
```

Comment: You can attach a load event listener to an iframe.

Comment: I read that the implementation of `load` for iframes was a little finicky, but looking back, that mainly applies to when an iframe is being loaded at the same time as the parent document, so I suppose the listener would work here. I edited my answer; thanks!

Comment: @theftprevention, the second one works perfectly, thank you very much!! I have no control over the error page since it's an external image service, only if it succeeds, can I call doneUploading, if it fails, everything just hangs as if the upload is still busy.

$('#uploadTarget').one('load', function() { var data = $($('#uploadTarget').contents()).attr('title');          console.log(data);});